# How can I render a completed CGI form as a PDF?

Tags: perl, session, pdf, cgi, render

I have an HTML form which a user may have filled in or partially filled in. I want to snapshot that state and render it as a PDF document. I've been using [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

I've tried this from both the client side and the server side, and the rendered result is always the original form, never the filled-in one.

I notice if I reload the filled-in form page I get back the filled-in form, but if I cut and paste the form's URL into a new window, I get the initial, non-filled-in form.

So I've convinced myself that, if I could use [`CGI::Session`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session) properly, I could successfully open a session identical to the filled-in session. I tried using [`CGI::Session::Plugin::Redirect`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session::Plugin::Redirect) with no joy. I *think* the key is that `window.open()` has to use the SID of the filled-in form window.

I don't have a lot of experience with CGI session management, so this has been a four-day quest to nowhere. Any advice is appreciated, even if it's to abandon this approach and go back to the more common post->render a new form in a new window, and generate the PDF from that. I'd like to avoid all of that if I can.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have the following HTML document on your web server:

*/var/www/html/index.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/process.cgi">
      <input type="text" name="foo">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you navigate to `http://hostname/index.html` in your browser, the webserver returns this document and the browser displays it.

When you fill in the text field in your browser, the document on the webserver doesn't change. So anybody who navigates to `http://hostname/index.html` will get the original, unmodified form. This is why you can't simply copy and paste the URL into another browser tab and get the filled-in form.

Most browsers use caching by default. When you fill in some fields in a form, the browser caches what you entered. When you reload the page, the webserver sends the exact same document as before* (i.e. the unmodified form), but the browser uses the cached data to fill in the form fields the way you had them. If you override the cache when you reload the page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in Firefox), the form fields will not be filled in. Note that neither the URL nor the document on the server have changed. This is why you can't copy and paste the URL into another browser tab after reloading the page and get the filled-in form.

`wkhtmltopdf` takes a URL, renders the corresponding page, and generates a PDF based on what is rendered. Based on the explanation above, it should now be clear why `wkhtmltopdf` always generates an image of the unmodified form.

### The solution

If filling in form fields doesn't change anything on the webserver, what *does* it change? It changes the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction), a structure describing the document in your browser that you can access using JavaScript.

One approach would be to use a client-side JavaScript PDF generator like [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf); since it runs on the client, it has access to the DOM that the user is interacting with, so it can "see" the values the user enters into the form fields.

---

* Actually, the webserver will typically send a `304 Unmodified` response to save bandwidth, but form caching works the same either way.

Comment: Thank You for all for taking the time to reply, these was very helpful. I'm a Perl guy , but we have a JAVA/DOM guy on the team who I'll discuss this with. I never heard of WWW::Mechanize::Firefox sounds interesting...

Comment: @user3250422 I thought about `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` and alternatives like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (a headless JS-enabled browser that doesn't require an X-server and I think is a little easier to set up), but I think you would have the same problem as with `wkhtmltopdf`: you would be fetching the unmodified form directly from the web server, instead of the version in the user's browser. You could POST the form contents to a script that gets the unmodified form with `W::M::F`, fills in the appropriate fields, and takes a screenshot, but that seems like a lot of extra work.

Comment: @user3250422 `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` *is* an excellent tool, though, and is quite popular for programmatically interacting with web pages that use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The [explanation from `ThisSuitIsBlackNot`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29519735/622310) is accurate about why your design is failing. Typing characters into form fields in a browser changes only your screen and the data in the memory allocated to the browser.

I suggest a different solution. The [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) module is a variant of [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) that uses a real browser application to retrieve and render web pages. It is mostly chosen when a site requires JavaScript support, but it is useful here because it has a [`content_as_png`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox#mech-content_as_png-tab-coordinates-target_size) method which returns a PNG image of the current page. Hopefully that is enough for you to build a PDF file with the required content

Comment: Our JS/DOM guy's ears perked up whenI said jsPDF ! Might be our ticket thanks again!